# Passing a variable through Java Script Executor in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

i want to pass a java variable to javascript..

this is part of my code:

```
String localArray[][] = new String[50000][9];
String strContratoNumero;

for(int i=1; i<10;i++){
    strContratoNumero = localArray[i][0];
```

I have tried this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('txtNr_Contrato_Plano_Trab').value=arguments[0]",strContratoNumero.substring(0,9));
```

but it doesn't work.

Can you please tell me how can i make send the values through variables in the above command?

PS: i am getting data from excel sheet.. but don't worry because this part is working.

Comment: I don't get what the deal is with that `for` loop you show. You say it does not work but you do not say how it does not work. Do you get a Java exception? Do you get a JavaScript error? Is something just not happening? What you want to do is quite doable but without the right details, it is hard to know what's wrong with your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use string concatenation?

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('txtNr_Contrato_Plano_Trab').value='"+strContratoNumero.substring(0,9)+"'");
```

Comment: Well, this will work until the OP tries this in a situation where there are quotes in the string that should be passed to the JavaScript side. (Probably not a huge risk for a contract number but could be a problem, generally.) What the OP wants to do is quite doable by passing the string as an argument. I do it all the time.

Comment: yep, it is of course doable.  offering an alternative `:)`